# Can you help identify this plant?

Tags: identification

Can you help identify this plant? I'm not sure what it is. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Unhappy Oleander? Leaves look close: https://www.google.com/search?q=oleander&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_rfOHr67SAhVMlFQKHW0sAU8Q_AUICCgB&biw=1069&bih=588

Comment: I guess OP means the one in the center, not the few branches in the foreground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the Grevillea varieties possibly, something like Grevillea superba http://esperancewildflowers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/grevillea-plurijuga-subsp-superba.html

Comment: Kudos for this ID Bamboo. I agree 100%. Grevillea is one of my faves.